# How to disable flask app.run() 's default message

Tags: python, logging, flask

When running flask app, like

```
... 
if __name__ is "__main__":
    app.run(port=self.port)

...
```

There are some messages for running.

```
* Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

How I disable all these messages?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the messages?

Comment: The answer is already in there, in the 4th line of the output.

Answer (score 14):

To disable Flask from displaying warning banner messsage about using a development server in a production environment, add the 2 cli lines before running flask:

```
from flask import Flask
import sys

cli = sys.modules['flask.cli']
cli.show_server_banner = lambda *x: None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='80')
```

https://gist.github.com/jerblack/735b9953ba1ab6234abb43174210d356

Comment: It works! Helped me to solve the case when flask app has to be run as Windows service (no stdout and no stderr).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN=true
```

Comment: Doesn't work on werkzeug >=2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I used to get below when I run flask app via `python app.py`

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

added below code block in my app.py to remove the default flask message completely

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True
cli = sys.modules['flask.cli']
cli.show_server_banner = lambda *x: None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import flask.cli
flask.cli.show_server_banner = lambda *args: None
```